# Simple way to update document from DTO?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this express code for my User endpoint. I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to implement the update for a user, where I can just pass mongo a DTO like I do for the create, rather than filling the fields in individually. Does mongoose have a way to populate an existing document with values from a DTO, since I can't use the constructor like in create?

```
exports.updateUser = function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({ name: req.params.name }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) { res.send(err); }

        //way to use DTO like create?
        if(req.body.profile.zipCode) { user.profile.zipCode = req.body.zipCode; }

        user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) { res.send(err); }
            else {
                res.json(user);
            }
        });
    });
};

exports.createUser = function(req, res) {
    var user = new User(req.body);

    user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) { res.send(err); }
        else {
            res.json({message: 'User added!', data: user});
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply all values from `req.body` to the document using a utility function like underscore's [`extend`](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#extend):

```
var _ = require('underscore');

exports.updateUser = function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({ name: req.params.name }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) { res.send(err); }

        _.extend(user.profile, req.body);

        user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) { res.send(err); }
            else {
                res.json(user);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

However, it's best to first sanitize `req.body` to remove any profile properties you *don't* want to allow the user to set themselves.  For example, if the user's id was also stored in the profile, you wouldn't want to allow them to change that:

```
delete req.body.userId;
_.extend(user.profile, req.body);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could instead use `findOneAndUpdate` together with a `$set` operator:

```
exports.updateUser = function(req, res) {
    User.findOneAndUpdate({ name: req.params.name }, { $set: req.body }, function(err, user) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("Something bad happened along the way");
        }

        res.json({message: 'Successfully updated user.'});
    });
}
```

In order for this to work, you need to pass an object matching the field names of your documents through `req.body`, just like you do when creating a user.

For example, if a user only updates their `name` and `email`, the object that you pass through `req.body` should have the following structure:

```
{
    name: 'UpdatedName',
    email: 'email@updated-address.com'
}
```

By only passing the fields that should be updated through the `body-parser` middleware, you make sure that only those fields get updated.

Comment: If I am correct, my validators won't run on this. Was hoping there was an elegant way to put values from a DTO into the document before calling `.save()`

Comment: @nw. If I understand correctly, you want a more elegant way to validate data from the client before updating the record and saving it?